# Suspicious newsletter subscriptions

Tags: email, spam, forms, spam-prevention

Since the last few days I have been receiving more newsletter subscriptions than usual. The emails and frequency look suspicious. Like every hour or two. I tested one of the emails with [cleantalk](https://cleantalk.org/blacklists) and I got:

> gracia_mattinson@xxx.xxx reported as spam 42 websites attacked, discovered Oct 14, 2019, last activity Oct 14, 2019 23:26:38.

I don't understand the goal of those subscriptions? Why would they be useful to a spammer? Is there a risk keeping them in my database except having bounces?

How to prevent these spam? I have a CSRF protection on the form, it doesn't seem enough. Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Webmasters! Your site may be used for creating a subscription bomb. https://www.spamhero.com/support/125230/I_am_being_attacked_with_tons_of_subscription_emails_wh I would consider fortifying your form to prevent this. I will keep poking around for more information.

Comment: And here... https://blog.goptg.com/60000-new-emails-this-is-what-happens-when-your-inbox-gets-subscription-bombed I will look into protecting forms when I get back from the hospital. The advice is to use CAPTCHA with 2 forms of verification. This is an important question! Cheers!!

Comment: So I think I understood, it's because I automatically send the last newsletter to the registered user. I have deactivated this for now.